# Unable to install PHP, MySQL on RHEL5

Tags: rpm, yum, rhel

I'm trying to install PHP and MySql on an Apache Web Server on a RHEL 5.7 VM. I have tried to do it with the following yum Remi and EPEL repos:

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
```

It looks like there are "Missing Dependencies" whenever I try to do this:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test install mysql mysql-server php php-common
```

Then, I get the following error:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit) is needed by package mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
php-cli-5.4.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) is needed by package php-cli-5.4.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libaio.so.1()(64bit) is needed by package mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl(DBI) is needed by package mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit) is needed by package mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl-DBI is needed by package mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
php-5.4.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: httpd is needed by package php-5.4.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
php-5.4.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 is needed by package php-5.4.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
php-5.4.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) is needed by package php-5.4.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 from remi has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL is needed by package mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd is needed by package php-5.4.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
Error: Missing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) is needed by package php-5.4.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
Error: Missing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 is needed by package php-5.4.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl-DBI is needed by package mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
Error: Missing Dependency: libaio.so.1()(64bit) is needed by package mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
Error: Missing Dependency: libgmp.so.3()(64bit) is needed by package php-cli-5.4.27-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl-DBD-MySQL is needed by package mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
Error: Missing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1)(64bit) is needed by package mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
Error: Missing Dependency: perl(DBI) is needed by package mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
Error: Missing Dependency: libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4)(64bit) is needed by package mysql-server-5.5.37-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (remi)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

I already have httpd (I can run service httpd start), and whenever I try to install libaio, I get this:

```
[root@mod2014 rpm-gpg]# yum install --enablerepo=remi,remi-test libaio libaio-devel
Setting up Install Process
No package libaio available.
No package libaio-devel available.
Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on [this](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/) webpage, there is no **libaio** rpm package in the repo you're trying to use. I would suggest you to include [this](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/) CentOS repo into your /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory or download everything [manually](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&limit=4&srodzaj=3&dl=40&search=libaio).

By the way, what is reason of using such an outdated RHEL distributive?

Comment: I installed (almost) everything manually, which worked for that error, but it's still saying httpd is needed, which I already have installed. Additionally, the CentOS repo says I need htmlview. I'm working on a free RHEL VM that they provisioned for me for my own testing, so I wasn't the one who picked the outdated one.

Comment: @Kristin, So what does yum answer you when you do `yum install httpd`?

Comment: @Kristin, and what package is owning your current httpd? `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/sbin/httpd`

Comment: yum install httpd: Setting up Install Process
No package httpd available.
Nothing to do
rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/sbin/httpd
error: file /usr/sbin/httpd: No such file or directory

Comment: @Kristin, it seems for me, that package httpd is not installed on your machine because the /usr/sbin/httpd is missing. You can check it with `rpm -qa | grep httpd`. I suggest that you'll see nothing. If so, just download the httpd package from CentOS repo and install it with `yum install` (don't use `rpm -Uvh` without urgent need).

Comment: @Kristin, please show me the content of the files in your /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory (update your post or use any website, pastebin or whatever). Centos Repo does not seem to be working.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll install that. I'm getting `/etc/mime.types is needed by httpd-2.2.3-82.el5.centos.x86_64`, but it's ok if you don't want to go through that too. I think you've answered my initial question :)

Comment: @Kristin, this is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=249223) about the deprecated version httpd that you're trying to use. It was fixed in 2007. Try to install **mailcap** package before httpd.

Comment: Well, it's not going to show up because i couldn't figure out how to add it. I just was trying to install the httpd rpm manually. I couldn't figure out what the url to the actual repo was in that giant list that you sent. They all looked like individual packages for each dependncy. When I added remi and epel, they had a .rpm url so i'm kind of lost.

Comment: Also, it says `package mailcap-2.1.23-1.fc6.noarch is already installed`

Comment: @Kristin, well it's seem to be difficult to find out the reasons, but if you want, I can merge your /etc/yum.repos.d/* files into the one that will (hopefully) make your yum work properly. However, I would suggest you to use up-to-date distribution (Centos 6.5 is nice indeed). I can't imagine why did that people provided VM with old RHEL to you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this gets VERY OLD and TIRED, when people who "answer" the questions are ASKING *WHY* do you want to do it this way (i.e., using "old" software & repositories).

Bottom line: There are *many* valid reasons - also, those same reasons for NOT UPDATING via Yum auto-updates and/or RHEL auto-updates, etc. My case, for example, Web host company kept us on OLD versions of mysql (5.0.96-community and 5.1), PHP (5.2.13) and Apache (2.2.15 and 2.2.22?) - and they refused to change some things (i.e., modify 'deprecated mysql_connect commands' and other commands) to the latest mysqli and/or PDO formats, SO, when we took over the site, the code WILL ONLY RUN USING *OLD* SOFTWARE. So, you see, there can be valid reasons for doing this.

So, to allow us time to figure out what is mysqli, and what is PDO and "how" do we change our software and code for those more updated (non-deprecated) products, we MUST STAY ON OLD CODE!

But, to answer original poster: you can do

```
yum --nogpgcheck localinstall some.rpm --nodeps
```

And then, via `--nodeps`, you will be able to bypass "dependency checks."